# How to fix `duplicate class com.google.firebase.components`?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I started to use the MLKit barcode scanner in my project and get the `Duplicate class` error when trying to run the app.
Also, I tried to `exclude firebase-common` and `exclude firebase-components`, but it didn't help, because it breaks push notification or MLKit scanner.

From Firebase and Google we use those dependencies:

```
playServices: [
   base     : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0",
   maps     : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0",
   location : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0",
   safetynet: "com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0",
],
firebase: [
   messaging: "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0",
   barcode: "com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:16.0.0"
]
```

```
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.AbstractComponentContainer found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component$$Lambda$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component$$Lambda$2 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component$$Lambda$3 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.Component$Builder found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentContainer found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery$MetadataRegistrarNameRetriever found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery$RegistrarNameRetriever found in modules jetified-firebase-common-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.0.0) and jetified-firebase-components-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0)

and more classes ...
```

Comment: `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1`

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: @user1974368 Yes, I updated firebase to the latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try updating it to the latest version of Firebase. There has been some changes in the underlying infrastructure in Q1.